# fgetcsv & glob - Removed limit but stopped at 10000 files

Tags: php, fgetcsv

I'm using fgetcsv inside a loop which generates the filename to be opened based on 
 glob() function.
It ran fine however it stopped at the file named 9999.csv which would lead me to believe there is a limit set somewhere however I have set the limit in the function to 0 ( no limit ) so am puzzled as to why it stopped processing the files

I have a background script running and new csv files are being generated every 5 seconds so there is no way it should have stopped ( I currently have 85,000 csv files in the directory and started the script when there was 48,000 files )

Here is my code, if anyone can find a way around this it would be great

```
$files = glob("*.csv"); ## need glob for wildcards as scandir does not work
foreach ($files as $value) {

  $fp = fopen($value, "r");

  while( !feof($fp) ) {
    if( !$line = fgetcsv($fp, 0, ',')) {
       continue;
    }

    $importSQL = mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT INTO `data` (`col1`,`col2`,`col3`,`col4`) VALUES('".$line[0]."','".$line[1]."','".$line[2]."','".$line[3]."')");
  }
  fclose($fp);
} 
echo "Last File Processed - ".$value;
```

**Edit **
Also just for debugging purposes :
The database type is MyISAM and now has 6,934,460 rows and is 872.9 mb

Comment: The way you've asked the question is weird a bit. What exact filename you have in your directory which was not processed?

Comment: I dont see whats weird about it .. I have over 85000 csv files named 0.csv all the way up to 85000.csv hence i said it stopped at the file 9999.csv

Comment: So if you remove file `0.csv` and `1.csv` it stops on `10001.csv` ?

Comment: yes , according to the script the last file processed was called 9999.csv

Comment: I did not ask for that. I've asked to remove 2 files from directory and check what will happen. Or just do `count($files)` to check if it reflects to the number of file in the directory.

Comment: and I answered .. if I removed 0.csv & 1.csv would mean it would stop at 10001.csv

Comment: count just returned 101723

Comment: that means that you have 101 723 filenames returned from `glob` function. no limits. I suspect you have nothing to worry about. You've processed all files. But last filename is `9999.csv` so you can try to reorder or do `echo $idx++."\n"` every time you open next file to see how many files processed.

Comment: yeah I figured that so I'm puzzled as to why the script only processed 10000 files

Comment: Just emptied the table so I can retest with your suggestion

Comment: Well its just passed 11000 and is nowhere near the records that were added to the DB previously so still puzzled why it said last file processed was 9999.csv , obviously wasn't the case --- Yep all files processed thats why it stopped .. it caught up with my other script creating the files
Thanks for your help